# Bootstrap multiple date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to implement the multiple date picker option in bootstrap modal popup. I have used jquery plugin for the same. However nothing seems to work. Please help me with the implementation. 
[project files](https://github.com/OmkarGadgil/HCI)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Set datepicker's z-index above the modal's which is 1050.

```
<style>
.datepicker {
  z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
}
```